# Why strtol returns wrong value?

Tags: c, strtol

```
char xs[7] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0'};
long ss = strtol(xs, NULL, 2);
```

after 2nd line ss is 2147483647, any ideas? following code is in the loop (outside it works fine)

Comment: `xs[]` is missing a null character termination.  Try `char xs[7+1] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0',0};`

Comment: @chux probably easier to see when written `char xs[7+1] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0',NULL};`  syntactic sugar obviously, ;-P

Comment: @SnakeDoc Better to use `0` or `'\0'` for the null character than `NULL` which is the null pointer.

Comment: Or even better: `char xs[7] = "0001010";`

Comment: @chux you are right. I'd use the `'\0'` then since when scanning the source quickly it will stand out easier (vim will highlight it, etc).

Comment: @John Bode `char xs[7] = "0001010";` is not a good idea as that does not have a null character terminator either.  Perhaps you meant `char xs[7+1] = "0001010";` or `char xs[] = "0001010";`

Comment: or, even `char xs[ ] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0',0};` will do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem can be fixed by making a minor change to the code.

Comment: strtol requires a string for input. a string is terminated by a nul char.  '0' is 0x30, a nul char is 0x00.  suggest appending a '\0' to the list of characters in 'xs'

Comment: @chux - not enough caffeine.  Was supposed to leave the `7` off.

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` expects a NUL terminated string. Your array declaration creates a 7 character array and populates all 7 positions with  non-NUL data. Thus, `strtol` actually continues to look up the stack (or through memory) until it finds a terminating character.

You have a number of options for declaring a `char` array and initializing it correctly. If it is a read-only array, I prefer:

```
char xs[] = "0001010";
```

which will create an array large enough to hold the string literal (including its terminating NUL).

Other options are shown in the comments above

```
char xs[7+1] = "0001010\0";
char xs[7+1] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0',0};
char xs[ ] = {'0','0','0','1','0','1','0',0};
```

The advantage of either my approach, or the final one above, is that you don't need to count the characters, and the compiler will adjust if you change the string.

In the first example above, `\0` is the escape sequence representing the ASCII NUL character. It is preferable to a plain `0` because (a) it has the correct type (`char`) for inclusion in a string literal, and (b) most syntax-aware editors will highlight it, as a NUL in the middle of a literal can have surprising results. For example

```
   strlen("abc\0def") == 3
```

Comment: `char xs[7+1] = "0001010\n";` looks suspicious.

Comment: `'\0'` and `0` both have type `int`

Comment: `'\0'` can be assigned to an int, just as 'A' can, but the underlying type is a character literal.